# Having to click div twice to activate animation in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, function, click

I have a hidden panel that slides in when you click on a div. You can then either close it by clicking the 'close' text or the dark background that fades in behind the panel. Once you close it and try to reactivate the panel you have to click it twice.

I was looking around on stackoverflow and it looked like i should change it from .click to .on and add in a e.preventDefault. However I couldn't get this to work.

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4nL4v/) showing the double click problem.

And here is my jquery:

```
var scrollbarWidth = parseInt(getScrollBarWidth (),10); //get width of scroll bars, assume its constant
$('#sauceThumb').on( "click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if($('#sauceDet').css("right") === "-9999px") // don't do anything if panel is already being shown
    {    
        $('#cover').fadeIn(200);
        $('#mainContent').addClass('blur');
        $('#sauceDet').animate({
        right: "0"
        }, 700, 'linear');
        var scrollPos = {
        top  : self.pageXOffset || document.documentElement.scrollLeft || document.body.scrollLeft,
        left : self.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop  || document.body.scrollTop
        };
        $('body, html').data('scroll', scrollPos).css('overflow', 'hidden');
        $('body').css('margin-right',parseInt($('body').css('margin-right'),10) + scrollbarWidth + 'px'); // add width to body margin
        window.scrollTo(scrollPos.top, scrollPos.left);
    }    
});
$('.close, #cover').on( "click", function()
{
    $('#sauceDet').animate({
        right: "-9999px"
    }, 1500, 'linear');
    $('#mainContent').removeClass('blur');
    $('#cover').fadeOut(200);
});

function getScrollBarWidth () {
    var inner = document.createElement('p');
    inner.style.width = "100%";
    inner.style.height = "200px";
    var outer = document.createElement('div');
    outer.style.position = "absolute";
    outer.style.top = "0px";
    outer.style.left = "0px";
    outer.style.visibility = "hidden";
    outer.style.width = "200px";
    outer.style.height = "150px";
    outer.style.overflow = "hidden";
    outer.appendChild (inner);
    document.body.appendChild (outer);
    var w1 = inner.offsetWidth;
    outer.style.overflow = 'scroll';
    var w2 = inner.offsetWidth;
    if (w1 == w2) w2 = outer.clientWidth;
    document.body.removeChild (outer);
    return (w1 - w2);
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this [**result**](http://jsfiddle.net/4nL4v/1/) what you want?

I change this line

```
$('#sauceDet').animate({ right: "-9999px" }, 1500, 'linear');
```

to

```
$('#sauceDet').animate({ right: "-9999px" },'linear');
```

The problem is the time from 1,5 Second

Comment: Exactly that but is there a way to do it without removing the time? As this helps slow down my animation.

Comment: yeah, I remove it to show you where is there problem... you can set to 600 for example...

Comment: Yep I see that I can put it up to 1000 but if it goes over 1000 it starts to cause the problem why is that? It needs to be more than 1000 really. Is there another way to fix this?

Comment: I make a `setTimeout` function for stop the animation... I increase the animation in this case for 2500... [see the result](http://jsbin.com/qurep/3)

Comment: Thanks what I decided to do was change it to add and remove a class and move the transition with CSS3 . Thank you for your help :)